# PyQt suddenly stopped showing QMessage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

This code was working perfectly yesterday but when I ran this code again today, it ignored the first if statement (the one which shows message) and direcly went to the elif statement. It should show a message if team_name is - " "(empty), or contain any special characters. I tried to put both ""(empty) and special characters in input field. Everything else is working fine, only the message isn't showing. Also, QMessageBox module is already imported.

```
team_name, ok = QtWidgets.QInputDialog.getText(MainWindow, "Team Name", "Enter Name Of Your Team:")
    if ok:
        if team_name.isalnum() == False:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Team Name")
            msg.setText("Invalid Team Name")
            msg.setInformativeText("Team Name Must Not Be Empty Or Contain Any Special Characters!")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.new_team)
        elif team_name.isalnum():
            self.team_name_lbl.setText(str(team_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, but you forgot to *[execute](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#exec)* the `QMessageBox()`.

```py
    if ok:
        if team_name.isalnum() == False:
            msg = QMessageBox()
            msg.setWindowTitle("Team Name")
            msg.setText("Invalid Team Name")
            msg.setInformativeText("Team Name Must Not Be Empty Or Contain Any Special Characters!")
            msg.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
            msg.buttonClicked.connect(self.new_team)
            msg.exec()
        elif team_name.isalnum():
            print("It works")
```